# Why does my Kotlin code fail the test case?

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently learning Kotlin. So in the course I'm doing I wrote this code:

```
package connectfour
import java.util.*

var rows : Int = 0
var columns : Int = 0

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val regex = Regex("[5-9]\\s?[Xx]\\s?[5-9]")
    //Print program title
    println("Connect Four")
    println("First player's name:")
    val p1 = scanner.next()
    println("Second player's name:")
    val p2 = scanner.next()

    while (true) {
        println("Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)")
        println("Press Enter for default (6 x 7)")
        val s = scanner.next()
        when {
            s.isBlank() -> {
                rows = 6
                columns = 7
                break
            }
            s.matches(regex) && s.isNotEmpty() -> {
                rows = s.substring(0, 1).toInt()
                columns = s.substring(s.lastIndex).toInt()
                if (rows !in 5..9) {
                    println("Board rows should be from 5 to 9")
                    continue
                } else if (columns !in 5..9) {
                    println("Board columns should be from 5 to 9")
                    continue
                } else if (rows in 5..9 && columns in 5..9) {
                    break
                }
            }
            else -> {
                println("Invalid input")
                continue
            }
        }
    }
    println("$p1 VS $p2")
    println("$rows X $columns board")
    println("\n")
    println("\n")
```

And this is the Output my code produces:

Connect Four
First player's name:

> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 5x5
> Anna VS Joan
> 5 X 5 board

Connect Four
First player's name:

> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 9X9
> Anna VS Joan
> 9 X 9 board

Connect Four
First player's name:

> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)

So my question is. When compared to the following code. Why does my code stop at the point it is stopping. My code fails the "Press Enter" test. I can't seem to find my mistake.

Other Code:

```
package connectfour

import org.w3c.dom.ranges.Range

const val MIN_DIMENSION = '5'
const val MAX_DIMENSION = '9'

fun main() {
    println("Connect Four")
    println("First player's name:")
    val firstPlayerName = readln()
    println("Second player's name:")
    val secondPlayerName = readln()
    val dimensionRegex = "\\d+[Xx]\\d+".toRegex()
    var boardDimension: List<Int>

    while (true) {
        println("Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)\n" +
                "Press Enter for default (6 x 7)")
        val dimension = readln().replace("\\s*".toRegex(), "")
        when {
            dimension.isBlank() -> {
                boardDimension = listOf(6, 7)
                break
            }
            dimension.matches(dimensionRegex) -> {
                boardDimension = dimension.split("[Xx]".toRegex()).map { it.toInt() }
                if (boardDimension.first() !in 5..9) {
                    println("Board rows should be from 5 to 9")
                } else if (boardDimension.last() !in 5..9) {
                    println("Board columns should be from 5 to 9")
                } else {
                    break
                }
            }
            else -> println("Invalid input")
        }
    }

    println("$firstPlayerName VS $secondPlayerName")
    println("${boardDimension.first()} X ${boardDimension.last()} board")
}
```

**Desired Output:**

Connect Four
First player's name:

> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 5x5
> Anna VS Joan
> 5 X 5 board
> Connect Four
> First player's name:
> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 9X9
> Anna VS Joan
> 9 X 9 board
> Connect Four
> First player's name:
> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)

Anna VS Joan
6 X 7 board
Connect Four
First player's name:

> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 7   x   9
> Anna VS Joan
> 7 X 9 board
> Connect Four
> First player's name:
> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 8  X   6
> Anna VS Joan
> 8 X 6 board
> Connect Four
> First player's name:
> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 9     X   5
> Anna VS Joan
> 9 X 5 board

Start test 2
Connect Four
First player's name:

> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 4x5
> Board rows should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 4X5
> Board rows should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 10x6
> Board rows should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 12x6
> Board rows should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 6x1
> Board columns should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 7X4
> Board columns should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 8x10
> Board columns should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 9x30
> Board columns should be from 5 to 9
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 9X5
> Anna VS Joan
> 9 X 5 board

Start test 3
Connect Four
First player's name:

> Anna
> Second player's name:
> Joan
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 6x
> Invalid input
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> X5
> Invalid input
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 10k6
> Invalid input
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 12Z6
> Invalid input
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> a  7x9
> Invalid input
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 5x8  t
> Invalid input
> Set the board dimensions (Rows x Columns)
> Press Enter for default (6 x 7)
> 9X5
> Anna VS Joan
> 9 X 5 board

Comment: If you want to use scanner replace the 3 invocations of scanner.next() with scanner.nextLine(). That way the newline is catched by the function and the newline input is not passed further to unintentially end the reading process before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is. When compared to the following code. Why does my code stop at the point it is stopping. My code fails the "Press Enter" test.

`val s = scanner.next()` on line 20 is your issue. The `next()` method looks for the next string you input. When you hit enter with no text *it's still waiting*. It does **not** return an empty string but will sit there and wait until you finally do enter something.

Your program isn't moving forward to your `when` statement (and thus the `isBlank()` check) because it is still waiting on the user input.